# How to get params current route from root app component. With help Router 3.0

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

How to get params current route from root app component? I need to track all routes from app root.

Now, I make it this way

```
this._router.events.subscribe(x => {
    if (x instanceof NavigationStart) {
        var data = this._router.parseUrl(x.url).root.children['primary'];

        if (!data) return;
        let segments = data.segments;

        let companyId: string = data[1].path;
    }
})
```

How to get by a param name?